# Update fancybox current slide content on button click with a new type

Tags: fancybox, fancybox-3

Is it possible to change the current slide (which is type inline) to type video (youtube) after clicking a button in the actual shown type inline content?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to quickly close and open new instance, if you would disable animations, then the change would not be noticable.

Comment: Do you have  an example how this is best done? @Janis? I've already tried that. Do I have to manually update the DOM-Element of the slide before closing/opening?

Comment: Could you create a Codepen/JSFiddle demo of your progress?

Comment: @Janis yes of course. https://codepen.io/jousch/pen/KKdjvMY

Comment: It could be done like this - https://jsfiddle.net/qLe62yh5/

Comment: Thank you very much @Janis. That seems work very well. I try to make your example looking like a real-world example and will add it as answer here. It’s so fantastic, thanks again!